# How to decompile assembly without have the dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, decompiler, ilspy

This question is based in ([ILSpy, how to resolve dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689505/ilspy-how-to-resolve-dependencies))

Well, the ILSpy library changed and now we don't have Ast Builder, like the most answers about this.

The instance `new ICSharpDecompiler` have a overload that can take a `ModuleDefinition` of `Mono.Cecil`, but I don't know if this ModuleDefinition is the new "Resolver" for this issue.

In the resume I need to decompile a assembly (C#, .dll) that I don't have the dependecies (dll), I need to read the assembly using `CSharpDecompiler decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(dll.Name + ".dll", new DecompilerSettings());` without have the dependencies, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution making a simple:

```
CSharpDecompiler decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler("name.dll", new DecompilerSettings() {ThrowOnAssemblyResolveErrors = false})
```

This will ignore the dependencies but the types with references will not be read.